# fastest way to shuffle matrix row

Tags: java, matrix

I need to shuffle the rows of a matrix, creating a new randomized matrix with all the same properties of the original one. Is there any approach faster/more efficient than the one I am adopting now?

```
private static SparseDoubleMatrix2D shuffleMatrix(SparseDoubleMatrix2D aMatrix, int[] ordering, int size) {
    SparseDoubleMatrix2D result = new SparseDoubleMatrix2D(size, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int row = ordering[i];
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            result.set(i, col, aMatrix.get(row, col));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

each time the method is called, a new ordering is given according to this other method:

```
private static void shuffleArray(int[] ordering, MersenneTwisterFast r) {
    for (int i = ordering.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        int a = ordering[index];
        ordering[index] = ordering[i];
        ordering[i] = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not really randomizing the matrix..

Comment: thanks, just added a couple of lines, hope it's clearer now. If still I am not randomizing anything, then please explain what I am missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of `SparseDoubleMatrix2D`. Presently you are shuffling the rows by re-assigning every element in the matrix, however, since only rows are being shuffled and not columns, you should be able to shuffle it by reassigning the references to each row only, which should cut down the processing time from O(size*size) to O(size).

To answer the OP's comment about deep copy, a good implementation of SparseDoubleMatrix2D would be something like this:

```
class Matrix2D {
    private int[] ordering;
    private MatrixRow[] rows;

    public double getValue(int row, int col) {
        return rows[ordering[row]].get(col);
    }
    ...
}
```

Ordering starts off looking like {0, 1, 2, ... n-1}. When you need to randomize, just set a new ordering array. That way, the original order which 
is the order of rows[] never gets changed.

Comment: Good idea, I am using SparseDoubleMatrix2D from JUNG but it comes from cern.colt.matrix.impl 
Would be nice to have a way to just reassign the references to each row, any pointer in that direction would be awesome

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JUNG or cern.colt.matrix.impl, but a quick look at their API doesn't seem to show any methods for controlling row references, so you may have to write your own SparseDoubleMatrix2D to support this.

Comment: A last question: I still need the original matrix to remain untouched, and run the randomization many times... Since I need to make a deep copy of the original one, is your suggestion still valid?